# Nuxt.js not accepting issue reports?

Tags: nuxt.js

There doesn't seem to be a way to file an issue for the Nuxt.js project or docs.

It seems to be a configuration issue on the cmty.app

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3710

Is there any way to file an issue?

Comment: Stackoverflow is their preferred way to ask questions.  "Nuxtjs.org -> Ecosystem -> Chat" goes to a dead chat server that redirects to a chat app requiring a binary install.  After fiddling with this for 15 mins, I just got way less excited about Nuxt.

Comment: Discord don't require binary install, you can use web version no problem. Vue community pretty much use a discord for most projects. Vue chat in discord too

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for having a bad experience!

You can submit questions, bugs and feature requests over [`CMTY`](https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/). If you cannot see a matching `version` in the list, write one in the field and you can submit your issue. However, questions will be closed in answered directly in `CTMY`. Bug reports and feature requests will stay open in GitHub to attach PRs and so on.

Looks like CMTY is somewhat unstable today. If you want I can reopen issues on the `nuxt/nuxt.js' repo if you can link them up.

You can also the official Nuxt-Discord (there is a web app as Aldarund pointed out) for faster communication.

PS: I'm not working on CMTY and am 'just' a collaborator/contributor to Nuxt